# Mongoose: Is it possible to use populate on a field of type array to return only X number of elements of that array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, orm, mern

I have this model:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  following: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "users",
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

I would like to use `populate` on the `following` field, **BUT** return only the first 5 elements of that array.

Is this possible to do this directly with populate?

I know I can do this array truncation lately after getting all the array elements. But, what I am doing is in a complex query, and I wouldn't like to complicate it any further.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#limit-vs-perDocumentLimit

> Populate does support a limit option, however, it currently does not limit on a per-document basis for backwards compatibility. For example, suppose you have 5 following:

### Limit

if you want to get a *total of 5 `following` regardless of the number of users*

```
const users = await User.find().populate({
  path: 'following',
  options: { limit: 5 }
});
```

> That's because, in order to avoid executing a separate query for each document, Mongoose instead queries for fans using numDocuments * limit as the limit. If you need the correct limit, you should use the perDocumentLimit option (new in Mongoose 5.9.0). Just keep in mind that populate() will execute a separate query for each story, which may cause populate() to be slower.

### perDocumentLimit

if you want to get a total of *5 following per user*

A special option that tells Mongoose to execute a separate query
for each `User` to make sure we get 5 `following` for each user.

```
const users = await User.find().populate({
  path: 'following',
  options: { perDocumentLimit: 5 }
});
```

Comment: Do you know how to query this in reverse order?